# this is an exercise from my college c class i cant seem to solve it someone help me out

Tags: c

Write a program that for a date read from SI (in the format DD MM YYYY) will print on standard output a message YES if the date is correct and possible, or NO if the date is not correct.

When deciding whether the date is correct or not correct, you have to consider the following factors:

- is the month between January and December (1-12)
- does the number for days correspond with the number of days in the specified month
  if the month is February, is the year leap?
  Leap years are those years who are divisible with 400, or they are divisible with 4, but not with 100

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int day,month,year;
        
    
    
        scanf("%d %d %d", &day, &month, &year);
        
        
        for(month=1;month<=12;month++){
    
    
            if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0) ) {
                printf("YES");
            } else
                printf("NO");
                
                }
    
        return 0;
    
    
    }
```

Comment: You're checking if the year is a leap year, but you're not checking if the month or day is valid.  You're also overwriting the value of `month`.

Comment: You don't need a month loop, instead you need an array of the number of days in each month (or use `switch` statement). Check the month is in range, the year is "reasonable", figure out if it's a leap year, and then check the day. Done.

Comment: how do i "check" in switch if the month is between (1-12) ?

Comment: my output needs to be yes or no

Comment: i cant print anything inside switch

Comment: If it is not found by the `case` statements you'll be with `default:` Use a flag: ok or nor ok. Set the ok flag to 1 at first. Any fault, set it to 0.

Comment: having a really hard time trying to understand what you are trying to say i dont know how to work with arrays is there any simpler idea that you have

Answer (score 0):

You need an array of the days in a month and then check if the month is between 1 and 12. If the month is exactly 2, you should first check for leap years.

Something like this:

```
int daysInMonth = {31, 28, ...}; //replace ... with actual information
if(month < 1 || month > 13) {
  //month isn't valid
  printf("NO");
  return 0;
}

month -= 1; //to convert to 0-indexed
if(month == 1 && ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0)) {
  //month is february and is leap year
  daysInMonth[1] += 1; //february now has 29
}

if(day < 1 || day > daysInMonth[month]) {
  //day isn't valid
  printf("NO");
  return 0;
}

//When getting to this point it means we have a valid date
printf("YES");
return 0;
```

Please note that this does not handle some **very** special edge cases, explained [here](https://blog.yossarian.net/2015/06/09/Dates-That-Dont-Exist). These include the days that don't exist because of the switch from Julian to Gregorian calendar. But I'm almost certain that these are not what the exercise was asking for anyways. You may also want to check against negative years, depending on the exact definition of a valid year.

Comment: @conce1ted You're welcome. I see you're new to stackoverflow, so you might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Basically you generally don't want to use comments to indicate which answer helped you, but instead upvote or accept the answer. As you are new you can't upvote yet, but you are  welcome to accept whichever answer helped you figure out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you don't need to loop [on the month].

You should get the number of days in a month by indexing into an array (vs. `switch`).

Adding some extra boolean flags can help simplify things.

Anyway, here's a refactored version with some descriptive comments:

```
// is the month between January and December (1-12)
// does the number for days correspond with the number of days in the specified
// month
// if the month is February, is the year leap?
//    Leap years are those years who are divisible with 400, or they are
//    divisible with 4, but not with 100

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int days_in_month[12] = {
    31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 31, 31, 30, 31
};

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int day, month, year;
    int month_valid;
    int leap_year;
    int max_days;
    int day_valid;
    int date_valid;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    if (argc == 3) {
        month = atoi(argv[0]);
        day = atoi(argv[1]);
        year = atoi(argv[2]);
    }
    else {
        if (0)
            scanf("%d %d %d", &day, &month, &year);
        else
            scanf("%d %d %d", &month, &day, &year);
    }

    // is month in range?
    month_valid = (month >= 1) && (month <= 12);

    // is it a leap year?
    leap_year = (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0));

    // get number of days in month [if month is valid]
    if (month_valid)
        max_days = days_in_month[month - 1];
    else
        max_days = -1;

    // february in a leap year has an extra day
    if (month == 2)
        max_days += leap_year;

    // is day of the month valid?
    day_valid = (day >= 1) && (day <= max_days);

    // is entire date valid?
    date_valid = month_valid && day_valid;

    if (date_valid)
        printf("YES\n");
    else
        printf("NO\n");

    return 0;
}
```